# Facing problem while using Custom Fonts

Tags: android, fonts, font-face, font-size

I have seen many links where the suggestion is add the desired font in assets and fonts sub-folder. But my Editor do not have the sub-folder font. Give me the required information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using eclipse, go the asset folder, right click on it and add a new folder and name it fonts.

Comment: please consider marking the question answered. Its a tick mark to the left of the answer.